# Estimote sdk issue in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, beacon, estimote

We have integrated the latest Estimote sdk in our iOS application.

While under review the apple’s review team notified us that the sdk had obfuscated code present in it.

Tried to contact Estimote but we are not getting any response from them.

Have someone faces similar issue??